# pd.DateOffet(years=) breaks down at years>333

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to subtract 2011 years from my index, however the pd.DateOffset function seems to stop working for years > 333. It outputs values that look like the one below from 334 onward. When subtracting from the year 2011.

```
2262-02-05 23:34:33.709551616
```

The reason I am doing this is instead of having dates like 2011, 2012 I want to have years like year 1, year 2. Is there a workaround for this?

I have applied it like this.

```
index_proxy = index_proxy - (pd.DateOffset(years=334))
```

where index proxy is a DatetimeIndex with dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Some input/output mappings

```
2011-07-18 --> 2262-02-05 23:34:33.709551616    
2011-07-18 --> 2262-02-06 23:34:33.709551616
```

if I replace 334 with 2010

```
2011-07-18 -->  1755-03-16 22:43:41.128654848

2011-07-18 -->  1755-03-17 22:43:41.128654848
```

After messing around with the number of years to offset there seems to be a cut off around 1677.

Comment: How are you applying `DateOffset` and to what inputs ?

Comment: index_proxy = index_proxy - (pd.DateOffset(years=334)), index_proxy is a date index that has dates in yyyy-mm-dd form.

Comment: Thanks - can you [edit] your question to include that and some example of ins/outs ? (a `DateIndex` doesn't have a formatting form btw... it's just errr, a date that's displayed however your locale says...)...